# Why doesn't the height modification of the button work?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm doing a bootstrap login container. I added a button `btn` and tried to modify its height. However the height does not change, whatever the value.
The difficulty that prevent me to solve myself the issue is that i only know this attribute to change a button height.

Here is the code for the button :

```
<button id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="height: 50%; width: 60%">Inscription</button>
```

The parent element is:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">  </div>
```

You can find a live example of the problem here :
http://www.bootply.com/9XnSOvBGOn

Why doesn't the height modification of the button work ?

Thank you.

Comment: Side note, you separate CSS rules with a `;`, not a `,`. So `style="height: 50%, width: 60%"` should be `style="height: 50%; width: 60%"`

Comment: Thank you @j08691 i edited my question, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna make it smaller try using: line-height instead
like this:

```
<button id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="line-height: 50%; width: 60%">Inscription</button>
```

or use an absolute height instead of percent.

Comment: Thank you @hatzaviv the attribute 'line-height' works.

Answer (score 0):

Your style line contains a comma, which is incorrect. It should be a semi-colon. Also, try using pixel values rather than percentages.

```
<button id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="height:50px;width:60px">Inscription</button>
```

Bear in mind that if you are using a percentage for height, you need to set the height of the parent div.

Comment: Thank you @Lee i edited my question for the semi-colon. About using pixel value, this is not the purpose as the height will remain even if the screen width changes.

Comment: It changed when I edited your live example with pixel values. - http://www.bootply.com/Bf6zDZyMXk

Comment: Yeah using pixels is alright, but as i said this is not the purpose as the height will remain even if the screen width changes. So i need to use percentage.

Comment: I don't think that's true, you don't _need_ to use percentages, you could use EM values for example. As mentioned, you can only use height percentage if you specify the height of the parent container, as that's where it gets the percentage from.

Comment: I edited my question. I added the parent element. How could I put the attribute height in it ?

Comment: By adding `height` as a css rule, although I really think you shoudln't be using percentage, even for mobile optimising, which is what I think you're getting at.. you shouldn't need to use percentages for height

Comment: I noticed that using percentage or pixel is the same if the screen width change. So I agree with you about using pixel.

Comment: I'm going to bow out of this one, as I'm starting to not follow what you mean about the screen width change. Why would the button change at all if the screen width changes? That's what I don't really get, it shouldn't need to change.

Comment: Never mind I already have the solution. Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct know. There may be an error in the parent element that contains the button (you work with percentage so it matters). Can you post the parent element?

Comment: what do you mean by "parent element" ?

Comment: You may have your button in a div. For example: <div><button></button></div> Div is the parent element.

Comment: If you set an abolute height to class col-xs-6, then you are going to be able to set a percentage height to your button.

Comment: I tried <div class="col-xs-6" style="height:absolute"> and then I I set a percentage height to my button, but it dosn't work.

Comment: An absolute height is for example this: <div class="col-xs-6" style="height:300px">